# Angular2 with ASP.NET 5 and Gulp

Tags: asp.net, angular, gulp

I am new at Angular2, have some common task to figure out. I am implementing Angular2 project with ASP.NET 5. All my scripts are located in Script directory, then Gulp compiles them into Root of my project next to Index.html. How about components, should they be located in root with ts--> js, html and css together? I am trying to compile with this config but components are not converted. What is wrong?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var typescript = require('gulp-tsc');

gulp.task('default', function () {
// place code for your default task here
});

gulp.task('compile', function () {
gulp.src([
     'es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
     'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
     'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
     'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
     'rxjs/**',
     'zone.js/dist/**',
     'core-js/**',
     '@angular/**'
], { cwd: "node_modules/**" }) /* Glob required here. */
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/node_modules'));

gulp.src('./scripts/systemjs.config.js') /* Glob required here. */
 .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/'));
gulp.src(['src/scripts/*.ts'])
    .pipe(typescript())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/app/'));
gulp.src('./scripts/main.ts') /* Glob required here. */
 .pipe(typescript())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/app/'));
});
```

Comment: You can keep original module/folder structure from your source folder, you just need to describe it in `systemjs.config.js` with `map` and `package` options. What do you mean by *"components are not converted"*?

Comment: thanks. I mean ts are not converted to js

Comment: You should create separate tasks for each gulp.src line you have.
Each task should then return the gulp.src line.
To execute tasks in a specific order, you should use the dependency parameter of the gulp.task method - see: https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/task-dependencies-in-gulp-b885c1ab48f0#.snxgeqfrj

Comment: It might be a better idea to use [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io) module bundler instead of concatenating files with Gulp, see a working example in [ASP.NET Core Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/aspnet-starter-kit)